# ViewSonic LCD Monitor Touch-input connector?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, touchscreen

I bought a used 15" ViewSonic LCD monitor (VP150m) and noticed that it has a 3.5mm connector on the back labeled “touch i/o”. I’m trying to figure out how to use the touch function but am having trouble finding anything useful.

First, I cannot find any information on what kind of cable it uses (TS, TRS, TRRS, etc.), or how to connect it to the computer.

Second, I cannot find touch drivers for it—though I can find a page that mentions how easy it is to install them.

Does anyone have any information on using the touchscreen function of the VP150m? Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: Is there a separate audio jack on the monitor?

Comment: Yes, yes it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [VP150m features and specification](http://fraulein.viewsonic.com/support/desktopdisplays/lcddisplays/proseries/vp150m/#specs) on ViewSonic website does not mention that this model supports touch.  It is possible that ViewSonic used the same chassis from a different model.

Comment: And left in the connector? `o.O`

Comment: I tried to look [into the connector](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DvQxw.jpg) and I think I saw what looked like a resistor or other component. I didn’t bother to open it to confirm because it looks like there is no actual plug inside, which means that the text etching on the outside of the chassis is superfluous for this model. I guess your suspicious is correct. (It would have been nice if they had at least put a little sticker over the words.)